# Why does junit dependencies have not installed properly?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit

I am trying to run an unit testing and I have already installed the dependencies. Below is the pom.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Lecture_1-2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

But when I am running my test case, it still gives me the error,

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'test'
```

I have tried reloading the maven project but it has not worked.

This is what I get when importing junit. Why is this?
[image: Cannot Resolve symbol junit?]

What is the reason for the issue?

Comment: I believe you also need to bring the org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine dependency. But the message you are seeing may be something different, it will help you more to provide the full stack trace AND the relevant code.

Comment: First try to build your project on plain command line...furthermore an example test class would be help ful and a log output because the message `Cannot resolve symbol..` indicates some problem with your test code?

Comment: @khmarbaise I have not coded anything in the test code yet.

Comment: In the upper right corner of IntelliJ there is a Button with a Maven symbol ("M") on it... You should press that button to reload the pom.xml by IntelliJ ...